# Is there a way to make the backdrop of mat-dialog clickable when the close is on disable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-dialog

I have developed a mat-dialog that only closes when I click on the close button that means it is set to disabled. I would like to have input in the background when my dialog is open. How can this be enabled?

Code:

```
// Important snippet from dialog component
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<KagListComponent>) {
    dialogRef.disableClose = true;
  }
```

```
// Important snippet from app component
/**
   * Open the dialog
   */
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      backdropClass: 'transparent'
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog will be closed!`, result);
    });
  }
```

I tried to activate the background with `hasBackDrop= true` in the function. Unfortunately it did not work. Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: you want grey backdrop in background of dialog ? Not understanding this line " I would like to have input in the background"

Comment: Hello, I wanted to make the background clickable when dialog disableClose = true. I solved the problem by setting hasBackDrop to false. I didn't have the call in my function before and thought it must be set to true.